# What is the Objective-C equivalent to an empty Swift OptionSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Please take a look at this simple Swift code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: interButtonDelay * Double(expanding ? index : index + 1), options: [], animations: {
            button.transform = expanding ? .init(scaleX: self.scale, y: self.scale) : .identity
            button.alpha = expanding ? 0.0 : 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
```

Here an empty array is passed into the `options` parameter. I would like to find out what is the correct Objective-C equivalent to doing this. I assume it should be passing 0, but I want to be completely sure. Unfortunately the docs not telling anything regarding this.

Comment: C Enums are ints, so 0 is a valid value to pass

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift's `OptionSet` was created to make bitmasks more pleasant to use. In Swift, you spell the combined value as if it were a collection; in Objective-C, it's an integral value, built with bitwise operators:

```
NSUInteger options = UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut;
```

The Objective-C equivalent to an empty `OptionSet` is therefore indeed just 0.